# asmack - make sent message don't shown in Gtalk

Tags: asmack

I have added online playing function for my chess game, with the help of asmack api. It works, but there's some minor issues left:

When I send/receive messages, these messages are not only received by by my game client, but also captured by Gtalk client on android phone. It's annoying and may bother user. How to make these messages captured just by my game client?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have forgot to implement a `MessageListener`?